# Defining a map of maps of slices of maps, with "assignment to nil" error, do I prepopulate or generate keys on the fly?

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm pretty new to Go, and am using it for some data manipulation

I have a python program that takes json input as a `dict of dicts of lists of dicts` as  seen below:

```
{
    "64": {
        "-117": [{
            "lat": 64.1121952,
            "loc": "Northwest Territories",
            "lon": -117.3539847,
            "id": "GmtNT",
            "name": "Gameti"
        }],
        "-147": [{
            "lat": 64.838,
            "loc": "Alaska",
            "lon": -147.716,
            "id": "FairbanksAK",
            "name": "Fairbanks"
        },
        {
            "lat": 64.9,
            "loc": "Alaska",
            "lon": -147.4,
            "id": "IcFgObAK",
            "name": "Icefog Observatory"
        }]
    },
    "71": {
        "-125": [{
            "lat": 71.985123,
            "loc": "Northwest Territories",
            "lon": -125.2464831,
            "id": "SchshrbrNT",
            "name": "Sachs Harbour"
        }]
    }
}
```

I am writing a Go script to generate this json for input. I already have a working go script to get data into this format:

```
siteIDMap := make(map[string]map[string]string)
```

Sample Output in terminal:

```
map[
 CydrvrNU: map[loc:Nunavut lat:70.476365 lng:-68.6012651 name:Clyde River]
 UkhktkNT: map[loc:Northwest Territories lat:70.7367504 lng:-117.7704441 name:Ulukhaktok]
 PrdhByAK: map[loc:Alaska lat:70.254704 lng:-148.3406 name:Prudhoe Bay]
 SchshrbrNT: map[loc:Northwest Territories lat:71.985123 lng:-125.2464831 name:Sachs Harbour]
]
```

However I am having trouble with the final step. I have been able to try and initialize what I suspect to be the correct data type `latLngMap := make(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string)`, and have tried populating it but apparently cannot without initializing every single lat/lng combo!

The Code I have so far to do this is as follows:

```
//Already have 'siteIDMap' created in above code not shown

slice2 := []map[string]string{} //empty slice that can be added to

//Init map of Lat/Lng to site data
latLngMap := make(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string)

// for every site in map
for k, v := range siteIDMap {
    loc := v["loc"]
    lat := v["lat"]
    lng := v["lng"]
    name := v["name"]

    m := map[string]string{"id": k, "lat": lat, "lng": lng, "loc": loc, "name": name}

    latFloor := strings.Split(lat, ".")[0]
    lngFloor := strings.Split(lng, ".")[0]

    fmt.Println(m, latFloor, lngFloor)

    latLngMap[latFloor][lngFloor] = append(slice2, m)

}
```

The last line gives the error `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`, which makes sense, since the lat/lng values are not yet entered in the map as keys

But for something as unwieldy as this, how do I initialize it?

Do I need a `map[-89 to +89] lat`, and for each of those `map[-89 to +89] lng`, and for each of those: `[]map[string]string{}`

If I do that, probably 90% of those lat/lon combos will be totally empty. Seems like an awful waste.

How can I create this data structure as it is being generated?

I've thought of creating a struct for this big nested data type, but Im new to Go and unsure if/how that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the nested maps as needed - you don't have to initialize the entire range of possible lat, lng pairs.

The issue is that `make(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string)` is initializing the map of `string` to `map[string][]map[string]string` but not the map of `string` to `[]map[string]string`. Thus when you assign `latLngMap[lat][lng]` the `[lat]` part is ok, but the maps for the `[lng]` part are not initialized (they are `nil`).

Thus, all you need to do is initialize the maps inside of `latLngMap[lat]` before putting anything in them. You can do this in your for loop over latitudes.

```
//Already have 'siteIDMap' created in above code not shown

//Init map of Lat/Lng to site data
latLngMap := make(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string)

// for every site in map
for k, v := range siteIDMap {
    loc := v["loc"]
    lat := v["lat"]
    lng := v["lng"]
    name := v["name"]

    // initialize nested map for this lat if it was not already initialized 
    // by a previous iteration
    _, ok := latLngMap[lat]
    if !ok {
        latLngMap[lat] = make(map[string][]map[string]string)
        latLngMap[lat][lng] = make([]map[string]string, 1)
    }

    m := map[string]string{"id": k, "lat": lat, "lng": lng, "loc": loc, "name": name}

    latFloor := strings.Split(lat, ".")[0]
    lngFloor := strings.Split(lng, ".")[0]

    fmt.Println(m, latFloor, lngFloor)

    latLngMap[latFloor][lngFloor] = append(latLngMap[latFloor][lngFloor], m)
}
```

Notice that I also changed where the slices inside the nested maps are being created. This will prevent bugs if two places have the same lat, lng. Previously if there were two the first would be overwritten by the second.

Here's a simplified version of the code running in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9Bvn8BDV0PS).

Comment: Made a minor edit (Should use LatFloor as a key, not Lat), but otherwise this is perfect. Thanks!